# Real time power bi dashboard update without refreshing the browser

Tags: powerbi, apiary.io

I was able to create dataset and add rows to the table using power bi Rest API methods via apiary. My dashboard is only updated with the data after refreshing the browser. What I need to do for experiencing the real time refreshing of the dashboard without manual browser refreshing?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution possible by code - afaik - is the refresh pulling with JavaScript's `setTimeout()`.

E.g., to refresh every 60 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   var iframe = document.getElementById('yourIFrameId');
   var url = iframe.src;
   iframe.src = url;
}, 60 * 1000);
```